# ASP.NET MVC5, two controller, with the same name in different folders

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two files called FilmController. One in the controller folder which displays my database data, and one in a folder called API which allows users to view data in json format.

My question is, in my nav bar i have an action link item that linked to the controller folder film file before i created the API one. Now it doesn't no which one to target. Is there anyway to target a specific one.

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Films", "Index", "Film")</li>
```

I want this to direct to the controller/film file.

Comment: try look at this http://haacked.com/archive/2010/01/12/ambiguous-controller-names.aspx/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the ActionLink helper to target a specific Controller class.

However you can create a second route definition in your RouteConfig.cs. Let this route point to another namespace. Then put your API code in this namespace:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "API",
    "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new[] { "MyMvcApp.Api" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who have similar issue having two controllers with the same name in different folder, consider using [Areas](https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/b/dhananjay_kumar/posts/areas-in-asp-net-mvc) in your ASP NET MVC project and put each of these controllers to a different area. Then if you use `@Html.ActionLink("Name", "Action", "Controller")` in your view it will always choose the controller based on the area you are in, and if you want to have a link to a controller from another area, you can use `@Html.ActionLink("Name", "Action", "Controller", new { area = "AreaName" }, null)`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using a standard controller as an api controler. One should be of type Controller, and the other ApiController, then they can both exist with the same name. @Html.ActionLink will only route to Controllers.

```
public class FilmController : ApiController
```